# Android - FATAL EXCEPTION: Error inflating class abLayout - Custom Style Does Not Resolve

Tags: android, xml, fatal-error, android-tablayout, forceclose

I'm getting a fatal error stating: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class

All the research I've done points to creating a custom style to resolve the issue:

[Got Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TabLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32732781/got-error-inflating-class-android-support-design-widget-tablayout)
[Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TabLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31712563/error-inflating-class-android-support-design-widget-tablayout/32895215#32895215)

or perhaps the SupportLibrary - or adding a missing background:

[android.view.inflateexception binary xml file line #1 error inflating class android.widget.relativeLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762720/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-1-error-inflating-class-andr)

However none of those solutions seem to resolve this force close issue and I'm not sure how it can be resolved.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

### ChatFrag.Java

```
public class ChatFrag extends Fragment {


...
    public ChatViewPagerAdapter adapter;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabLayout allTabs;
...

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        setup = Setup.getInstance();
        isLoaded = false;
        MessagesFrag = this;


        View main = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_chat, container, false);

      ...
        getAllWidgets();
        setupViewPager();

        ...

           private void setupViewPager() {
        adapter = new ChatViewPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
        activeChats = new ActiveChats();
        visitors = new Visitors();
        adapter.addFragment(activeChats, "Active Chats");
        adapter.addFragment(visitors, "Visitors");
        setViewPageAdapter();
    }

       private void getAllWidgets() {
        viewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
        allTabs = (TabLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    }

        private void setViewPageAdapter() {
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        allTabs.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                if (tab.getPosition() != viewPager.getCurrentItem()) {
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                if (tab.getPosition() == viewPager.getCurrentItem()) {
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

### activity_chat.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</LinearLayout>
```

### LogCat

```
                                                                                         --------- beginning of crash
09-21 11:08:15.434 25875-25875/com.redacted.redactedmobile E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                         Process: com.redacted.redactedmobile, PID: 25875
                                                                                         android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                                             at com.redacted.redactedmobile.ChatFrag.onCreateView(ChatFrag.java:84)
```

### Build.gradle

```
dependencies {
  ...

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23+'
...


}
```

### v21 styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">#227900</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">#227900</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#227900</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">#227900</item>
        <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="android:Theme.Material">
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">#3F51B5</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</item>  
        <item name="android:colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
    </style>
    <style name="MyCustomTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
        <item name="tabIndicatorColor">#FF4081</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can delete that style try this instead of styling for changing tab indicator color:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/your-color-name"/>
```

and set your color in colors...

Comment: I changed it as suggested - still crashing on the same line with the same error message

Comment: do you delete this line:  style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"?

Comment: Yes 

 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

Comment: I'm not sure if it helps point things in the right direction (believe me - I'm stumped too) but all of this was previously implemented (and working) as an activity - however when I started moving it all over into another application I'm working on which implements it as a fragment - everything went to hell in a hand basket.

Comment: can you add your fragment code of adding viepager and tablayout in your post?

Comment: for test remove  app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/darker_gray" and run the app...are you getting the error again?

Comment: sorry, its my mistake i edited my answer ...check it...it should be app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/darker_gray"

Comment: I tried as you stated - same error - same place (updated Java code above to include the ViewPager)

Comment: do you check last changes of my answer?? i try that in my app and it works fine

Comment: Using @ color or @ android or removing it entirely still causes the app to crash at line 9 android.support.design.widget.TabLayout in the XML file

Comment: allTabs .setupWithViewPager(viewPager); add this in setupViewPager()...if it dosn't work change getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tabs); to main.findViewById(R.id.tabs);

Comment: It's crashing at line 84 which is View main = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_chat, container, false); so it's never even hitting setupViewPager() 

Here is a more detailed view of things: http://pastebin.com/TtRtSWD5

Comment: last change recives in my mind is getChildFragmentManager() instead of getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()

Comment: I'm not sure how that would make a difference considering it crashes well before that line (I tried it regardless - still crashing in the same place as the original post stated)

Comment: It must have something to do with the line View main = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_chat, container, false); [where it is crashing] or above